# Error message when running sncli

Tags: command-line, installation, python

I'm trying to run [sncli](https://github.com/insanum/sncli). I followed installation instructions, restarted, tried to run it and got this error message:

**C:\Users\ben>sncli**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts\sncli-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('sncli==0.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'sncli')())
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\simplenote_cli\sncli.py", line 1356, in main
    sncli(sync, verbose, config).gui(key)
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\simplenote_cli\sncli.py", line 1052, in gui
    self.sncli_loop = urwid.MainLoop(self.master_frame,
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urwid\main_loop.py", line 115, in __init__
    screen = raw_display.Screen()
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urwid\raw_display.py", line 92, in __init__
    fcntl.fcntl(self._resize_pipe_rd, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined
```

Can someone tell me what is causing this behavior or how to fix this problem?

Comment: Ask sncli developpers.

Comment: Actually the traceback indicates a problem in the dependent package [`urwid`](https://pypi.org/project/urwid/). The code in `raw_display.py` ignores the error if `fcntl` cannot be `import`ed, with a comment `# Windows`, yet then plunges ahead and tries to call `fcntl.fcntl` later on in the code regardless. This appears to be a bug in the package itself; I guess it was never tested on Windows.

Comment: The obvious workaround is to not use Windows; you should find that your life improves tremendously.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows for another possible workaround.

Comment: The developer described it was working on Windows (had a binary download for Windows) but presumably never tested it in that environment (based on the reference you provide, I would guess not).  I would love to not use Windows--if you can convince my very large organization, I'd be thrilled.   I don't have the chops to make those kinds of changes myself--I can code simple scripts but this looks beyond me.   Thanks!